# Asp.net C sharp using button to submit data and relocate within page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

What I want to do is on a page, there is a basic textbox form in an "InputSection" to get input from users, then when user hit preview button (asp button) at the bottom of form, the data are gather and provided in a sorted format and displayed below the "Input Section", a section called "PreviewSection", before the submission to the database. The preview process is using asp label to receive the direct reference from the textbox on the same page, not go through server/database yet, something like,

```
LbPrevQuestion.Text = TBQuestion.Text;
```

I have no problem to do the data collection so far, and display in the preview section when the preview button is hit. But the problem is the page always goes back to the top of the page. What I tried was,

the button:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btPreview" runat="server" Text="Preview" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btPreview_Click"/>
```

code behind:

```
            protected void btPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Response.Redirect("Contact.aspx#PreviewSection");
        LbPrevQuestion.Text = TBQuestion.Text;

        }
```

when the button is hit, the input content is wiped out... What would be optimal solution for this? thank you very much.

Comment: Do you need to execute specific server-side functions or can you do without a Postback?

Comment: @Marco, for the preview button, I don't have to do anything from server-side.

Answer (score 0):

FIrs off i think that what you are needed to achieve, can be achieved using javascript or jquery only client side without a postback. If you strictly want to execute some processing at server side then you  may want to use the following server side way for retaining the scroll position.

If you want to maintain the scroll positions after postback then `maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"` attribute is what you are after. You can specify this attribute at page level in the @page directive in aspx page or
you can also define this in web.config file in the  section if you need this in all pages of your application.

```
<system.web>
  <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true">
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

http://madskristensen.net/post/maintain-scroll-position-after-postbacks

Comment: That is great if javascript or jquery can do that. Could you provide some hint? thanks a lot.

Comment: share the javascript code you tried and i will help to make it work